# Hibernate JPA cannot fetch new record after immediately saving it(within ms) by non-primary key(email,type) but can fetch by primary key(id)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My system has a *patient* entity that contains email(string), type(integer) fields, both non primary, not unique and not null fields along with other fields and of course a primary key id. 
After I save a new patient entity, when I search the entity in the database by jpa query *findById* it works perfectly fine and it fetches that new entity that was just saved few ms ago.
But when I search the newly saved entity by email and type by jpa query *findByEmailAndTypeAndEmailIsNotNull* it returns nothing but if I run the very same *findByEmailAndTypeAndEmailIsNotNull* query after 1 second of saving that new entity then it returns that newly saved entity.
Can some one diagnose the problem, is it even related to JPA? or with Database itself?

Edit:

```
@Transactional
public synchronized Patient addPatient(PatientProfileDto patientProfileDto, Integer facilityId)
        throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException, EntityNotFoundException, ClientException {
    // some code

    performPatientCreationValidations(ownerDto, ownerDemographicDto.getNationality().getId(), Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE);

    // patient creation

    patientRepository.saveAndFlush(patient);

    // some code to link patient to other entities
}

private void performPatientCreationValidations(...params)
        throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException, ClientException {
    if (patientRepository.findByEmailAndTypeAndEmailIsNotNull(patientDto.getEmail(), PatientType.OWNER.getId()).isPresent()) {
        // throw error
    }
}
```

If I hit the API 5 times in a row with neglible delay then 2 duplicate patient would get created, however on the last 3 apis hits it will throw error as it should. It should have also thrown the error upon 2nd api hit it receives. Also note the adding of patient is synchronized function so when one api hit is completed saving the patient then another api hit acquires lock on function n go on.

Answer (score 3):

> After I save a new patient entity, when I search the entity in the database by jpa query findById it works perfectly fine

`JpaRepository.findById()` works fine as it takes the entity from Hibernate's 1st level cache, not from the database, because inserting into the database is usually deferred until necessary, e.g. until your session is flushed. An entity can be fetched from the 1st level cache only by its id.

So you have to either flush the Session manually with `JpaRepository.flush()`, or use `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush()` instead of `JpaRepository.save()` or execute your operations within one transaction. In this case your requests share one session and Hibernate is going to flush its cache as soon as it gets a new query for the same entity.

Comment: I used saveAndFlush and it worked just with in that function, I mean now if I query by email and type just after saving(with flushing) it in same function, it is returning me the new record. But if I call some other function that is fetching by email and type the query is still not returning the new record with in milli seconds of creating it.
I also tried using .flush() in the other function just before the query to fetch by email and type, but even then it does not return new record.

Comment: I think your another function is executed in a separate transaction, this is why you don't "see" the data. As I've mentioned in the answer you should either execute operations within the same transaction, or execute the second operation only after the saving transaction has been committed.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me more on how to handle this bug? how would I know if my save transaction has been committed, is there any way? or is there any JPA solution to this problem?

Comment: Please update your question and include the code where your face the issue.

Comment: I have added code snippet, upon multiple API hits with neglible delay, when the second api hit process to evaluate patientRepository.findByEmailAndTypeAndEmailIsNotNull it get false so a duplicate is created.

Comment: Well, from your code I see that you query the data before saving it. Have you tried to reorder operations?

Comment: No they are in perfect order, first validation runs and if there exist no patient with email and type then the validation is passed and new patient is created with that email and type. The problem is if you hit the API let's say 2 times with negligible delay (with same patient data) between them then the saved result(patient) of 1st API hit will not be available to the 2nd API hit processing. Well if you didn't understand it still, I can text you explanation in chat

Comment: Try adding `@Transactional` over `addPatient()` method.

Comment: it is already there, nvm I mistakenly missed that line while copy pasting code snippet.